# How to use Recommended Fit API for Arraylist as the fittedEntityOrElement in Timefold?

Tags: timefold

I am working with Timefold Recommended fit API and when i try to call recommended fit api with a List as a fittedEntityOrElement  I got an error

```
//orders is an arrayList
    
return solutionManager.recommendFit(planningModel,
            orders,
            orders-> orders);
```

Logs :

**Maybe add a @PlanningId annotation on an identifier property of the class (class java.util.ArrayList).**
**Or otherwise, maybe change the @PlanningSolution annotation's LookUpStrategyType (not recommended).] with root cause**
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The externalObject ( ... ) cannot be looked up. Some functionality, such as multithreaded solving, requires this ability.**
**Maybe add a @PlanningId annotation on an identifier property of the class (class java.util.ArrayList).

Comment: Can you please share your domain model? I do not understand how the element ever became a `List`.